# Can I use 16 GB RAM with my MacBook Pro 7,1?

Tags: macos, memory, startup

I just picked up 16GB of RAM for my MacBook Pro, running the newest OS X. According to the NewEgg reviews, it should work in it. However, once I boot up, it shows the Apple logo and, after a few seconds, the spinner just freezes.

If I boot into my Windows 7 partition, it lists 16GB as installed, and 15.7GB available. Why, then, is OS X not recognizing it?

I've tried each of the sticks themselves (1x8GB), and OS X still freezes. The RAM came as 2x8GB and are PC3-10600 @ 1333 MHz.

I've tried holding `D` as the computer boots, but it just gray screens for a while, then jumps to the Apple logo.

It seems to me that 16GB may not work, but why then does the same hardware, just Windows 7 successfully run?

Comment: @geoffc: It's a 2.4 GHz Core 2 Duo. It's the provided one at my new job, and eclipse is tearing up the 4GB it has in it atm. My personal one has 2x4GB, but I apparently didn't do enough research before assuming that all OSX supported 16gb. I still don't understand why Win7 reports it as there though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Your Mac needs to meet specific criteria for this to work. In the case of the 2010 Macs, here’s what you must have:
>
> - a Mac mini (Mid-2010), a MacBook (Mid-2010) or a 13” MacBook Pro (Mid-2010)
> - Mac OS X 10.7.5 or later
> - the latest EFI firmware update for your system
> - the proper specification memory modules

See [Certain 2010 MacBook, MacBook Pro, and Mac mini models join the ’16GB’ MaxRAM club](http://blog.macsales.com/16302-some-2010-mac-owners-can-get-more-ram-than-they-thought) for details.

You will need (2x8GB) 16GB DDR3-1066MHz SODIMM. Anything faster like a DDR3-1333MHz or DDR3-1600MHHz SODIMM will fail to boot the machine.

Comment: Or, if you're a cheapskate like me, you can [mess with the EEPROM on a 1333MHz stick](http://blog.nu42.com/2013/02/mid-2010-macbook-pro-71-with-16-gb-ddr3.html). It worked for my Mid-2010 13 inch MacBookPro 7,1, but don't try it if you are nervous about that kind of tinkering.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mactracker, the MacBookPro7,1 is a 13" MacBook Pro and it only supports 8 GB of RAM. (For machines that support 16 GB, it mentions that Apple says it supports 8GB but it'll actually work with 16.)

So OS X probably just doesn't know how to talk to 8 GB sticks on that chipset. My recommendation would be to return the RAM and get 2x4 GB.

Comment: I figured as much, after more heavily researching it. Any thoughts as to why Win7 can see it? Is it perhaps just a Firmware issues?

Comment: Windows 7 has better support than OS X for that chipset? Apple usually doesn't bother supporting what they decide they don't want to, and that appears to be something they decided they didn't want to support.