# 8GB 1333mhz SODIMM in Macbook Pro 13" 2010 (7,1) alongside original 2GB stick

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I understand that 8gb modules are not officially supported in this MBP. However, this indicates that they are, as long as they are 1067mhz modules:

[Can I use 16 GB RAM with my MacBook Pro 7,1?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52157/can-i-use-16-gb-ram-with-my-macbook-pro-7-1)

I also understand that while 1333mhz modules are not supported, if they are paired with a 1067mhz module, the EFI automatically downclocks the faster module, and they both run at 1067mhz, eg:

http://tylermilner.com/?p=342

Here's my question:

Is is likely to work if I buy an 8gb 1333mhz module and pair it with one of the existing 2gb 1067mhz modules?

The reason for this over an 8gb 1067mhz or 2x4gb are:

1. I get more RAM (10gb) than replacing with 2 x 4gb
2. I can upgrade in future if I want (add an 8gb 1067mhz stick)
3. It's much cheaper - 8gb 1333mhz modules are far cheaper in the UK now than 8gb 1067mhz

Comment: I believe it's 1066 MHz, not 1067.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, but it's not recommended.

You should always use the same module, also I believe that way you got some performance benefit. MacRumors has a [post](http://guides.macrumors.com/Matched_RAM_on_Intel_Macs) about this.

Also, I believe your MacBook Pro won't support more than 8 GB of RAM according to the post, but that I'm not sure. Check out Apple's guide or technical documents for these information.

Another thing to be aware of is if your machine supports 8 GB on a single stick.

This is what I suggests. Buy two matching 4 GB 1066 MHz DDR3 RAM for your MacBook Pro. That way, you won't get into any trouble. It might cost a little more, but it's much more reliable.

Comment: Agreed. Macs can be very picky about RAM and it's best to just avoid the frustration altogether if you can. I have the same MacBook and if you really need 16 GB of RAM chances are you should be doing whatever you're doing on a different machine altogether. 8GBs of ram should be sufficient and you should be able to find 2x4 for less than $50.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkVEg2X6cbo
Has a video of a Mid-2010 13in Macbook Pro running 16GB of Ram. Its the only Macbook Pro that can use more than 8GB. 
http://blog.macsales.com/16353-owc-announces-maxram-memory-upgrades-to-16gb-for-2010-mac-mini-macbook-and-macbook-pro
Has an  article in which they tested 2010's and their compatibility to use 16GB. Due to the latest EFI release only the 13" MBP is compatible and uses all 16GB of ram. For just over $100 I'd just get the 16GB and call it a victory. I have a 2010 17" and I'm hoping that the same happens to us in a future EFI release.